# Formatting two decimal places or currency of double Java

Tags: java, format, double, decimal, currency

I want to figure out how I can format the output as money. As I am a beginner at Java, I would like the most simple solution possible although I am open to all suggestions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    int numUnits;
    double price;
    String item;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // get the data
    System.out.println("How many units?");
    numUnits = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("What is the price?");
    price = scan.nextDouble();

    scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the name of the item?");
    item = scan.nextLine();

    //calculations
    double totalCost = numUnits * price;

    System.out.println(numUnits + " units of "+ item + " were purchased for $"+
    price + " each for a total cost of $" + totalCost);

   }

 }
```

Comment: [`NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(totalCost)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance())...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are a number of ways you might be able to do it, you could use `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`, which will allow you to format the value based on the current locale properties...

```
System.out.println(numUnits + " units of "+ item + " were purchased for $"+
price + " each for a total cost of $" + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(totalCost));
```

You could also format the `NumberFormat` to suit you needs by getting a reference to the instance first...

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
// Customise format properties...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    double amount =500.0;
    NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "US"));
    System.out.println(currencyFormatter.format(amount));
```

You should use proper locale for which ever currency you awnt to use